# O que é considerado ao ordenar um campo varchar? Sendo preenchido por números

Tags: sql, select

Tenho uma tabela com os aniversariantes do mês, por um motivo de utilização aqui devemos armazenar este como `varchar`. Na utilização do mesmo é necessário ordenar pela data do mais recente ao mais velho, o mesmo utilizou este comando:

`SELECT * FROM m_aniversariantes order by dia;`

E obtivemos este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para solucionar tiver que fazer este outro select:

`SELECT * FROM m_aniversariantes order by CAST(dia AS INT);`

Que retornou da forma que precisavamos.

> Minha dúvida é, o que o primeiro SELECT considerou para ordenar a lista?

Comment: Ordenação alfanumérica.

Comment: Não sei ao certo, e não consigo verificar o que vou dizer, mas acho que seria como um array de posições de caracteres, e na ordenação considera cada ordem, `dia[0]` então ordena a primeira todos no array na primeira posição e compara, e então vai para o próximo. Agora para a ordem desse primeiro valor do array, acredito que seja por algum tipo de tabela como `ASCII`

Comment: Não sei se estou falando bobagem, mas parece que ele listou os dados como se todos os campos fossem letras (mr. obvious). Acontece muito isso no excel, onde você manda listar de forma crescente e acaba acontecendo a mesma coisa. Se definir o campo em "números", ele lista os números de forma correta. Acredito que seja a mesma coisa aí, pode reparar que a query respeita a ordem do decimal (pode ver que ele pula do 18 para o 20 porque o 2 é maior que 1, e do 29 para o 3, porque o 3 é maior que 2), e quando você deu um (dia as INT) ele transformou esse varchar (modo letra) em int (modo número).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os dados foram ordenados como texto (ordenação alfanumérica) ascendentemente, como é o tipo de dados da coluna. É a conhecida ordem alfabética.

Existem algorítmos que otimizam o processo de ordenamento, mas, para fins práticos, ele é feito comparando os caracteres a partir do caractere mais a esquerda com o caractere da posição correspondente nos outros registros avaliados. Em seguida avalia-se o próximo caractere, e esse ciclo segue sucessivamente por todos os caracteres (use como referência o maior conteúdo).

Dessa maneira, nas listas comuns no dia a dia, o algorítmo faz com que `Adriana` apareça nas listas de chamada antes de `Ana`, por exemplo. Mesmo a segunda tendo somente 3 letras, o 2º caractere de `Ana` (`n >> U+006E`) é maior* do que o segundo caractere de `Adriana` (`d >> U+0064`). *Se nessa lista (e se fosse possível registrar alguém assim) tivesse alguém chamado de `1berto`, ele apareceria antes de `Adriana`, inclusive.*

<sup>**** Baseado nos códigos de caractere da [Tabela Unicode](https://unicode-table.com/pt/#basic-latin). Podem haver variações em cada banco, dependendo de como são tratados os caracteres acentuados, o encoding do dado, tratamento de maiúsculas e minúsculas e por aí vai.***</sup>

Nesse ordenamento, os números e caracteres especiais comuns sempre antecedem as letras na questão de precedência, como você pode conferir na tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) ou [UNICODE](https://unicode-table.com/pt/#basic-latin).

Isso causa um efeito contraintuitivo quando estamos tratando somente com números, como é o seu caso, pois **489 sempre aparecerá antes de 75** (porque `4 (U+0034)` é menor do que `7 (U+0037)`), por exemplo, e assim por diante.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado por compartilhar e faz todo sentido mesmo a forma que foi ordenado. Grato amigo pela explicação.

Answer (score 2):

Ele considera como uma leitura em ordem alfabética, pegando o primeiro valor, como "1" e "2" vem antes do "3" ele considera eles primeiro, já que é um campo texto e não importa o valor total e sim carácter por carácter.

Comment: Exatamente! +1.